# How to concatenate special characters in regex

Tags: php, string

I have the below statement which uses regex

`preg_split('/DELIMITER '.$delimiter.'|DELIMITER ;/', $sqlString);`
and `$delimiter` is equals to $$ or // or other double special character, but when using characters like $$, we have to use escaping. In my case i want to use `$delimiter` as variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape them:

```
preg_split('/DELIMITER '.preg_quote($delimiter, '/').'|DELIMITER ;/', $sqlString);
```

A slightly more readable version using `sprintf()`:

```
$pattern = sprintf('/DELIMITER %s|DELIMITER ;/', preg_quote($delimiter, '/'));
$result  = preg_split($pattern, $sqlString);
```